# Which faults of dual transistors on isolated dice must be considered according to IEC 60335-1?

Tags: safety, standard, fault, transistor-array

I got the task to upgrade one of our products to comply with the requirements of IEC 60335-1, which means, that no safety function must be lost in case of a single component fault. To save space and cost, I often times use dual transistors for various task, be it in the three phase inverter or various driver circuits.

Now, according to chapter 19.11.2 of the standard, I must consider:

> short circuit of any two terminals of an electronic component, other than an integrated
> circuit. This fault condition is not applied between the two circuits of an optocoupler;

In the terms and definitions under 3.9.1, an electronic component is defined as:

> part in which conduction is achieved principally by electrons moving through a vacuum, gas or
> semiconductor

Based on this, I would conclude that a dual transistor with isolated dice is actually comprised of two electronic components and I don't have to consider shorts from one transistor to the other.

A prime example would be a half-bridge built of a dual MOSFET, where one of the transistors is used for the high-side and the other for the low-side. Depending on how the standard is to be read, I'd have to consider a short from high-side drain to low-side source or not. Our internal expert for the 60335-1 is not sure, how to interpret this.

Does anyone of you have concrete experience on this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Purely as a comment, I wonder how you can be sure that a matched pair is in fact two separate dice. One of the best 'matched pair' devices is the LM394, which is definitely one die; in fact it is multiple transistor cells in a lattice with junction isolation between cells.

Comment: I would leave matched pairs aside here and refer only to components that use separated dice. For power MOSFETs and the small signal components I use, this is usually the case.